# Script doesn't stop

Tags: python, pyqt5

This is the code

Entrypoint.py

```
   def Data_For_MakePdf_Db(self):
      mese = self.MakePdf_Strip_Month_select.currentText()
      anno = self.MakePdf_Strip_Year_select.currentText()
      MakeStrip(anno, mese)

      return ### Breakpoint here
```

and MakeStrip.py

```
class SpecialStyledItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._values = dict()

    def add_text(self, text, row):
        self._values[row] = text

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        row = index.row()
        if row in self._values:
            option.text = self._values[row]
            option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter


class MakeStrip(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, anno, mese):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI(anno, mese)

    def initUI(self, anno, mese):
        self.title = "MAMbo - Strips di '%s' '%s' "%(mese, anno)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(50, 100, 900, 800)
        self.callTable(anno, mese)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tableWidget)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 169, 70, 20))
        self.button.setObjectName("button")
        self.button.setText("close")

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

        self.show()
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        pippo = 0   ### Breakpoint here


    def on_click(self):
        print('Clicked')
        # Functions.message_handler(message = "THIS WILL CLOSE THE APP")
        return


    def callTable(self, anno, mese):

        # Create table
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.move(100, 700)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(33)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.special_delegate = SpecialStyledItemDelegate()
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(self.special_delegate)

        h_header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        h_header.hide()
        for i in range(h_header.count()):
            h_header.setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        v_header = self.tableWidget.verticalHeader()
        v_header.hide()
        v_header.setDefaultSectionSize(13)

        self.tableWidget.setSpan(1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.tableWidget.setSpan(0, 0, 1, 3)
        ...
        pluto = 0


   def on_click(self):
       print('Clicked')
       return
```

I use pycharm

Main problem
If I run the script I see for a fraction of second the result of Makescript even if there a push button
Alternative problem
If I debug it I need to put some breakpoints as shown in the scripts to see the result of the script
I know that the debugger keeps alive the connection but why do I need to put breakpoints in those positions to see the result?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your issue. Is it because in the `Data_For_MakePdf_Db` function you're creating a `MakeStrip` instance that is almost immediately closed?

Comment: `Data_For_MakePdf_Db` calls `MakeStrip` which creates a strip (may be you remember you helped me). Once the strips is shown there is a button in the displayed widged which waiting for to be clicked. `self.show()        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)` If I run the script everything is closed as soon as `MakeStrip` has made the job, If I debug I need to put breakpoints as shown in the posted piece of script to be able to us the button. In the end what I want is: wait for the button to be pressed then returno to tha script which calls 'Data_For_MakePdf_Db' which is called `MakePdf'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the following line:

```
    MakeStrip(anno, mese)
```

What happens there is that you create an instance of `MakeStrip` which has absolutely no reference. The result is that it's created and immediately garbage collected as soon as its `__init__` returns.

Imagine doing something like this:

```
    def Data_For_MakePdf_Db(self):
        list()
```

As soon as no reference to an object is left, python automatically destroys it. In the case above, you create an instance without any reference, so it gets immediately deleted.

Note that creating a *local* reference (a variable that exists only in the function) might be a solution, but since there is no locking, you'll have almost the same results, because the function will immediately returns, causing the instance to be destroyed as well:

```
    def Data_For_MakePdf_Db(self):
        strip = MakeStrip(anno, mese)
```

A possibility is to create a persistent reference, by making the object a member of the current instance:

```
    def Data_For_MakePdf_Db(self):
        self.strip = MakeStrip(anno, mese)
```

This has some, possibly unwanted, side effects: first of all, you could still switch between the current window to the new one (which will probably make things a bit confusing), and, most importantly, if you call `Data_For_MakePdf_Db` again while another MakeStrip window already exists, it will be probably destroyed and replaced by a new one.

A better and more consistent solution is to have `MakeStrip` a subclass of [QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html) instead, and use its [`exec_()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec): it will make it a [*modal window*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) and will return control only when the window is finally closed.

```
    def Data_For_MakePdf_Db(self):
        MakeStrip(self, anno, mese).exec_()

class MakeStrip(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, anno, mese):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI(anno, mese)

    def initUI(self, anno, mese):
        # ...
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.accept)
```

Note that in *this specific case* we can even create the dialog without the local or instance reference, thanks to the fact that `exec_` creates an event loop that blocks the execution until the dialog is closed.

This is always a good idea, though, as you might need to know if the dialog was actually "accepted" or "rejected", or need access to some of the dialog's objects.

In that case, a local reference is required:

```
    def Data_For_MakePdf_Db(self):
        dialog = MakeStrip(<b>self</b>, anno, mese)
        if dialog.exec_():
            print(dialog.tableWidget.rowCount())
```

<sub>PS: capitalized names should always be used only for classes and constants, *not* for functions, so it should be `data_for_MakePdf_Db`; while you can name your function as you like, this standard convention is highly suggested, as it improves readability (it makes clear distinction between classes and functions). Read more on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your more than comprehensive explanation. In the meantime, I learned things I didn't know existed. And I will do everything to learn to capitalize :)

Comment: Im sorry but had to remove the accepted flag since I get some errors during debugging. `self.button.clicked.connect(self.accept)` gives error: `'MakeStrip' object has no attribute 'accept'`. Restored `...connect(self.on_click)` ## 'def Data_For_MakePdf_Db(self):
        self.strip = MakeStrip(anno, mese)` locks the dimensions of the output window to those of the calling 'Class' ## using `MakeStrip(self, anno, mese).exec_()` gives error `'MakeStrip' object has no attribute 'exec_'`

Comment: @steza removing an accept flag is not a problem, but: 1) before accepting an answer, you should test proposed solution and accept it only if it *does* work for you; 2) if you have an issue, use comments to ask for clarifications. In this case, I mistyped the inherited class (as explained in the answer, it should be QDialog, not QWidget).

Comment: Its perfect now. Didn't read carefully your answer. Thank you